# Multiform Wizard / Stepper save data in laravel php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I need to design a form using (multiform wizard or stepper) that saves Data in different tables, Suppose a user fills three forms and saves the data in three different tables, the next time when user login the form should start from the 4th stage, and the user can also edit the save form, the tables are different it does not save in one table how to design such multiform in laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy, Assume you have already data in the database and also have prepared either an HTML page with 4 forms (as many you want), if your forms are all placed on one page then query all the data from the database using DB object or eloquent model(maybe from one table or different) then pass the data to view, after that fill the input fields using `value="{{ $data->name }}"` attribute, for saving each form you can send each form separately via post method

this wizard utility is different to design and needs, if you have further help feel free to comment below